# Debugging Mastermind Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

Basically what is happening is when i run this code and i type in numbers to guess what the number is

e.g. 1000 it will say

> "You got 0 numbers right!"

which means that the second number is 1.

> How could I fix this problem?

```
print("You have selected Hrd mode.")
randomNumber = GetNumber()
userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
while len(userChoice) != 4:
    userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
while userChoice != randomNumber:
    hits = [str(i+1) for i in range(4) if userChoice[i] == randomNumber[1]]
    many = (sum(n == c for n, c in zip(randomNumber, userChoice)))
    if hits:
        print("You got "+str(many)+" numbers right!")
    else:
        print("You got none right")
    userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
    while len(userChoice) != 4:
        userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
print("Congratulations! You got it right.")
```

Comment: split line `many = ...` to separated commands and put `print()` inside to see what values you have in variables in every loop.

Comment: `hits = ...` and `many = ...` do almost the same - you can use `many = len(hits)`  BTW: Are you sure you need `1` in `randomNumber[1]` in `hits = ..` ?

Answer (score 0):

Variable `hits` seems to be useless here, delete it and use variable `many` to check if user found something.

```
print("You have selected Hrd mode.")
randomNumber = GetNumber()
userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
while len(userChoice) != 4:
    userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
while userChoice != randomNumber:
    many = (sum(n == c for n, c in zip(randomNumber, userChoice)))
    if many != 0:
        print("You got "+str(many)+" numbers right!")
    else:
        print("You got none right")
    userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
    while len(userChoice) != 4:
        userChoice = [int(i) for i in list(input("Enter 4 numbers.\n"))]
print("Congratulations! You got it right.")
```